# Ionic back button animation not working

Tags: javascript, animation, button, ionic-framework, back

I have a problem with my back-button.

I want to a special animation when the back button in clicked and really tried everything but can't make it working.

This is my button:

```
<button class="button button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i>
    Back
</button>
```

This is my code in js

```
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/test.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
        $scope.modal.show();
    });
};
```

I really googled a lot and tried very much to handle this issue, but can't cope with it.

Hoping you can help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You want a back button that opens a modal, why? What kind of animation are you looking for when hitting the back button?

Comment: I've choosen the modal because it was recommended in the web. If you know, how I can influence the animation I would be grateful. In my special case I want ti slide the next view from left to right.

Comment: Look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/VLwLOG), go through the tabs and you'll have the option to go back, is this something similar you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Sam5487. I'll have a detailed look an give a feedback. Thank you in advance! Cheers

Comment: Hi Sam. I've checked the code and the thing is that it seems not to be a back button but a link. Have you a hint especial for a back-button? Thank you and cheers, Sven